# eevee rendering problem weird shadows on surface / artifacts / looks hollow

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows, artifacts

Heyo,

I am getting these weird shadows on the surface when rendering with eevee, but it looks fine with cycles. I already turned on soft shadows and increased cube & cascade size, that didnt help (i guess as these shadows should not actually be there?).
Any help is much appreciated!

Eevee (shadow / artifact problem):
[image: Eevee (shadow / artifact problem)]

Cycles (looks ok):
[image: Cycles (looks ok)]